# Airflow: Schedule a cron job every first thursday of the month in morning

Tags: cron, airflow, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I am planning to schedule airflow job every first, second and third thursday of the month and 8am ET. I am looking for cron job schedule

`0 15 * * 4 [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ] && command`

I tried above but not sure how `[ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ] && command` works in airflow.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab.guru to check your cron expressions. Although you might have a simpler time by simply scheduling it for every Thursday and start the DAG with a ShortCircuitOperator that skips all other tasks if it isn’t in the first three Thursdays of the month.